# A typo or not in principles of Algebraic Geometry on page 29. (by Griffiths and Harris)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

When I read page 29 of *principles of algebraic geometry*, it claims that any real differential form $\omega$ of type $(1,1)$ gives a hermitian form $H(\ ,\ )$ on each tangent space. The form $H$ will be positive definite if and only if for any $v\in T_z'(M)$,
$$
\sqrt{-1}\cdot \langle \omega(z),v\wedge \bar{v}\rangle>0. 
$$
I think this may be $<0$? Can anyone help about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it's a typo.

One quick check is to work this out for the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb C$, namely $\omega = dx\wedge dy$. Substituting $x = \frac 1 2 (z +\overline z)$, $y = \frac{1}{2i}(z-\overline z)$ gives the formula
$\omega = \frac{i}{2}dz\wedge d\overline z$, and therefore
$$
\sqrt{-1} \left\langle \omega(z), \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}\right\rangle = -\frac 1 2 <0.
$$